# How to launch a server with a python code?

Tags: python, server

I am using the Stanford Core NLP Server. I would like to launch it from a python file.

To launch it from a **command prompt** I use :

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05
java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -tiemout 15000
```

I tried to launch it from a **python file** containing this code :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\maell\PycharmProjects\Preprocessing\launch_NLP.bat'])
```

with launch_NLP.bat containing :

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05
java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -tiemout 15000
```

The output is like this :

```
C:\Users\maell\PycharmProjects\Pre-processing>cd                     
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05>java -mx1g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -tiemout 15000 
[main] INFO CoreNLP - --- StanfordCoreNLPServer#main() called ---
[main] INFO CoreNLP - setting default constituency parser
[main] INFO CoreNLP - warning: cannot find edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz
[main] INFO CoreNLP - using: edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz instead
[main] INFO CoreNLP - to use shift reduce parser download English models jar from:
[main] INFO CoreNLP - http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
[main] INFO CoreNLP -     Threads: 12
[main] INFO CoreNLP - Starting server...
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(Unknown Source)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer.run(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:1427)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer.main(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:1523)
[Thread-0] INFO CoreNLP - CoreNLP Server is shutting down.
```

**How can I do to let my server running and not shutting down once the line is past ?**

Comment: Your port is busy give a differnet port or kill the process using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simpler error:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

Either kill the process running on port 9000 or run in another port and it should work next time.

Comment: Thanks, it was obvious : I don't know how I missed it !

Answer (score 1):

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

It says that the port is already used, try with a different port in launch_NLP.bat like 9001.